# Running Spark job in Oozie using Yarn-cluster

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, oozie, hue

I had created a Spark Job using Oozie which configure run on yarn-cluster.
    The Spark program is written in Scala and is a very simple program which just initialize SparkContext, println("hello world") and stop the SparkContext.

Below is the workflow.xml:

```
<workflow-app name="My_Workflow" xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.5">
    <start to="spark-0177"/>
    <kill name="Kill">
        <message>Action failed, error message[${wf:errorMessage(wf:lastErrorNode())}]</message>
    </kill>
    <action name="spark-0177">
        <spark xmlns="uri:oozie:spark-action:0.1">
            <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
            <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
            <master>yarn-cluster</master>
            <mode>cluster</mode>
            <name>MySpark</name>
              <class>com.test1</class>
            <jar>/user/hue/oozie/workspaces/tl_test/lib/testOozie1.jar</jar>
              <spark-opts>--executor-cores 2  --driver-memory 5g --num-executors 2 --executor-memory 5g</spark-opts>
        </spark>
        <ok to="End"/>
        <error to="Kill"/>
    </action>
    <end name="End"/>
</workflow-app>
```

However, i was getting the following error:

```
 Failing Oozie Launcher, Main class [org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.SparkMain], main() threw exception, Can not create a Path from an empty string
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not create a Path from an empty string
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.checkPathArg(Path.java:127)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.<init>(Path.java:135)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.<init>(Path.java:94)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.copyFileToRemote(Client.scala:191)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client$$anonfun$prepareLocalResources$3.apply(Client.scala:254)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client$$anonfun$prepareLocalResources$3.apply(Client.scala:248)
        at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.prepareLocalResources(Client.scala:248)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.createContainerLaunchContext(Client.scala:384)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.submitApplication(Client.scala:102)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.run(Client.scala:623)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client$.main(Client.scala:651)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.main(Client.scala)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:569)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:166)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:189)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:110)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
        at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.SparkMain.runSpark(SparkMain.java:105)
        at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.SparkMain.run(SparkMain.java:96)
        at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.LauncherMain.run(LauncherMain.java:46)
        at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.SparkMain.main(SparkMain.java:40)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.LauncherMapper.map(LauncherMapper.java:228)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:54)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:453)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:343)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalContainerLauncher$EventHandler.runSubtask(LocalContainerLauncher.java:370)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalContainerLauncher$EventHandler.runTask(LocalContainerLauncher.java:295)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalContainerLauncher$EventHandler.access$200(LocalContainerLauncher.java:181)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalContainerLauncher$EventHandler$1.run(LocalContainerLauncher.java:224)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

    Oozie Launcher failed, finishing Hadoop job gracefully

    Oozie Launcher, uploading action data to HDFS sequence file: hdfs://MYRNDSVRVM350:8020/user/oozie-oozi/0000084-150828094553499-oozie-oozi-W/spark-156b--spark/action-data.seq

    Oozie Launcher ends
```

Please help as i'm totally stuck already.
Thanks.

Comment: Your workflow definition could be useful here.

Answer (score 2):

I meet the exactly same wired problem.  It turns out that multiple spaces in `<spark-opts>` cause this un-informtive error.  You have two spaces between `--executor-cores 2  --driver-memory 5g`.

Answer (score 1):

`Can not create a Path from an empty string` <- Spark is trying to stage your code, but your Oozie workflow doesn't provide the jar path, hence the empty path exception.

Providing the jar path in Oozie will fix this

Comment: Appreciate your quick reply. May I know the "jar path" u mentioned is the Spark Jar? If yes, the jar is in the "/user/hue/oozie/workspaces/temp_folder/lib/". However, i still could'nt get it correct.

Comment: Its' the jar containing your application - you have to package it first with set or maven and provide the full path to that jar, not just the parent folder

Comment: Below is the spark workflow: I already set it to full hdfs path but i still having same error.
 <spark xmlns="uri:oozie:spark-action:0.1">
  <job-tracker>MYRNDSVRVM350.bison.local:8032</job-tracker>
  <name-node>hdfs://MYRNDSVRVM350.bison.local:8020</name-node>
  <master>yarn-cluster</master>
  <mode>cluster</mode>
  <name>MySpark</name>
  <class>com.test1</class>
  <jar>hdfs://MYRNDSVRVM350.bison.local:8020/user/hue/oozie/workspaces/hue-oozie-1441794007.08/jar/testOozie1.jar</jar>
  <spark-opts>--executor-cores 2  --driver-memory 5g --num-executors 2 --executor-memory 5g</spark-opts>
</spark>

Comment: copyFileToRemote -> Spark is expecting a local, not a remote HDFS jar path

Comment: Hi Erik, based on link : http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.2.1/submitting-applications.html. The application jar could be in local or hdfs. I had try to run the jar which located in hdfs using spark-submit and it's working fine. I wonder is this a bug for HUE?